# Protect a URL with a custom stateless authentication mechanism using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I have a Spring REST application, being run on an embedded Tomcat via Spring Boot. I have various classes annotated `@RestController` with methods which are REST endpoints. I have Springfox Swagger, which produces Open API Specification JSON under the URL `/v2/api-docs`. Everything works fine.

Now I would like to protect the `/v2/api-docs` with the following authentication mechanism.

- The user supplies a username in the `Username` HTTP header, and a password in the `Password-Utf8-Base64` header (this is a base64 encoding of the UTF-8 encoding of the supplied password).
- A back-end method (already existing) checks the username/password, and checks that they have authorization to view this URL.
- There should be no session, the headers should be supplied with every call and the authorization check done every call.
- If the authentication information is incorrect, a 401 or 403 error should be supplied to the client. A 401 in case the username/password is wrong, or 403 in the case it's correct but they don't have access to the URL. There should be no redirects to HTML login pages etc., as this is a REST application only.

I am thinking, Spring Security is the right way to do this? Because with it, I should be able to specify, without altering the Springfox code offering the `/v2/api-docs` endpoint, that that endpoint should be secure via the above authentication mechanism.

I am a bit of a loss to know where to begin. [Spring Security's Getting Started Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/#initial) describes how to redirect to a login page in case the login is wrong. I think I can create by own [UserDetails](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/builders/AuthenticationManagerBuilder.html) which performs the authentication but how do I get access to the HTTP headers to find the supplied username/password? How do I send the 401 vs 403 status codes?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need basic authentication for REST (see [the example](http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-basic-authentication/)).

The only difference the token passing. Instead of 2 headers the solution expects one defined like this

```
String plainClientCredentials="myusername:mypassword";
String base64ClientCredentials = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(plainClientCredentials.getBytes()));

HttpHeaders headers = getHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64ClientCredentials);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, looks great. How do I use something other than the `inMemoryAuthentication` for the user database, with `userDetailService` right? But that is an interface which returns a `UserDetails` which has a `getPassword`, does the `UserDetails` represent the data the client has supplied, or does it represent the user in the database (in which case why does it have a `getPassword` method, passwords are usually hashed?) How do I return 401 vs 403 based on if the user is allowed to use the API or not? (as returned by my custom method)?

Comment: I am not using basic auth, but instead other headers. Is there a way to get Spring Security to read the username/password from custom headers?

Comment: If you need a custom `userDetailService` you should return `UserDetails`. It has username and a password. Then the username/password is compared with provided (in case of basic auth spring extracts the username/password from the token and compares with the returned by userDetailsService.

Comment: I see, thanks very much for the help. About "It has username and a password", we store our passwords hashed, so I don't know the password. Do you know what to do in this case?

Comment: I guess you can modify your logic to active basic auth. Add a custom filter before spring security filters, in the filter wrap your request, get necessary data from the custom 2 headers and generate the "Authorization" header as it was described in the answer.

Comment: Actually what I really want, is logic like `add("/v2/api-docs", () -> { call the existing method that I have to check the username/password from http headers, throw 401Exception, throw 403Exception if appropriate }`, is there anything like that?

Comment: In case of hashed password you need custom password encoder (see http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-password-encoding-bcrypt example). So in the UserDetailsService you return encoded password. Spring security uses the password encoder and encodes password provided by auth. Then en coded password is compared with one from UserDetails.

Comment: 401 exception is described in the tutorial above. I don't have immediate answer for 403 but it's definitely possible. I did something like this but would require a bit more efforts.